# Schema for Document with changeable user id

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I get such data (lets call it `event`) from many machines and I want to put them into `mongodb`:

```
   `event`
   {
    "payload":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "user":{  
      "user_sid":"S-1-5-21-2242820312-3698568055-2602798999-1000",
      "user_login":"john1"
     }
   }
```

later, this user could change his machine and new id will be generated for him - `user_sid`

new entry with new user_sid

```
   `event`
   {
    "payload":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "user":{  
      "user_sid":"S-1-5-21-2242820312-3698568055-2602798999-5555",
      "user_login":"john1"
     }
   }
```

So, all historical data after change cannot be associated in queries with new ones.

I have two ideas to handle this:

First is to make collection.users for holding user_sids and link user._id to event collection.

1. When new event with new `user_sid` come, new user will be added and
   new event will be linked with new user_sid.
2. Then, application user will be able to recognize john1 has change `user_sid` and could merge these users.
3. Old user.user_sid will be replaced with new one so old _id references in historical data need no change, new event will get _id
   with updated Old user.user_sid and new user.user_sid will be
   deleted.

Second is to make collection.users for holding user_sids but no referencing it in `event`. collection.users will hold every new `user_sid` for particular user and in queries put all `user_sid` for that user

Because I`am just starting with NoSQL I need advise with one is better?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add a user `_id` to the event document:

```
{
    "payload" : "xxxxx",
    "user" : {
        "user_sid" : "9rjvq835hgq0845uhr",
        "_id" : 1231231231,
        "user_login" : "john1"
    }
}
```

The path to the `user_sid` field is `user.user_sid`. I think it's better just to call it `sid` since the association with a user is obvious from the embedding and doesn't need to be repeated in the name.

Comment: ok but, `event` of same user can come, but with different `sid`. and then i end up with two user_sid entries of same user. and that is ok. then admin can notice that this sids are of same user and merge user documents in one. so all old `user_sid` should be updated